# apache don't rewrite index.php and others

Tags: apache2, url-rewriting

I have problems with my rewrite rules, I want that `http://example.com/b/abc` calls `banner.php?b=abc`, that works. But when I type `http://example.com/index.php?mode=mybanners` it will call `banner.php?b=index.php?mode=mybanners` (or something like this). My `.htacces` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule b/?(.+)$ ./banner.php?b=$1
    RewriteRule i/?(.+)$ ./banner.php?bi=$1
</IfModule>
```

Some ideas to let `/index.php` interact normal?

Answer (score 0):

Try below rules :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
    RewriteRule b/?(.+)$ ./banner.php?b=$1
</IfModule>
```